# Make div child pre elements all have the same width if one is over 100% using css

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I'm formatting a diff in the browser, I have a parent `div` wrapper and then each line of the diff file is displayed as a `pre` tag.

The `pre` tags display one per line and if they expand greater than 100% of the parents then you can scroll to see the rest of the line.

This works perfectly, however there is a small issue where only the pre tag that is longer than 100% is longer, the rest all stop at 100%. How can I ensure they all have the same width if one is over 100%?

If this can be done in pure html and css that would be perfect, a jQuery solution however would be very simple.

```css
  .diff-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
    margin:20px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    position: relative;
  }

  .diff-wrapper pre {
    background:transparent;
    border:0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    border-radius:0;
    display: inline-block;
    height:28px;
    line-height:28px;
    margin:0;
    min-width:100%;
    overflow: visible;
    padding:0;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    position: relative;
    white-space: pre;
    word-wrap:normal;
  }

  .diff-wrapper pre.added {
    background-color:#ddffdd;
  }

  .diff-wrapper pre.removed {
    background-color:#fee8e9;
  }
```

```html
<div class="diff-wrapper">
    <pre>+ some short text here</pre>
    <pre>+ some short text here</pre>
    <pre class="added">+ some loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text here</pre>
    <pre>+ some short text here</pre>
    <pre class="removed">+ some short text here</pre>
    <pre class="removed">+ some short text here</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want all `<pre>` to have the same width as the longest `<pre>`?

Comment: @nem035 Yes so the formatted colour backgrounds don't just randomly end like they do in the snippet.

Comment: You can set `pre` to `display:table-row;` but it won't support `padding` etc if that's ok.

Comment: @Pangloss best solution yet but it removes the borders as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

Add another container into your `.diff-wrapper`

```
<div class="diff-wrapper">
    <div class="diff-content">
        <pre>+ some short text here</pre>
        <pre>+ some short text here</pre>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

And add this CSS

```
.diff-content {
    display:table;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, messes up the width of the wrapper?

Comment: Just updated the answer, if you want the wraper to keep the width and be scrollable you need to add another container.

Answer (score 1):

Built off of a couple different answers here. Added an additional `<div>` to handle the display and preserve the width, while the `diff-wrapper` actually handled the overflow. I also adjusted the `<pre>` elements to `display: block;` to actually extend the full width for the `background-color` and so the padding is calculated with the width.

```css
  .diff-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
    margin:20px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    position: relative;
  }
  .diff-wrapper > div {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .diff-wrapper pre {
    background:transparent;
    border:0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    border-radius:0;
    display: block;
    height:28px;
    line-height:28px;
    margin:0;
    min-width:100%;
    overflow: visible;
    padding:0;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    position: relative;
    white-space: pre;
    word-wrap:normal;
  }
  .diff-wrapper pre.added {
    background-color:#ddffdd;
  }
  .diff-wrapper pre.removed {
    background-color:#fee8e9;
  }
```

```html
<div class="diff-wrapper">
    <div>
        <pre>+ some short text here</pre>
        <pre>+ some short text here</pre>
        <pre class="added">+ some loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text here</pre>
        <pre>+ some short text here</pre>
        <pre class="removed">+ some short text here</pre>
        <pre class="removed">+ some short text here</pre>
    </div>
</div>
```